# sqlite3 - how to list out database name using .databases command?

Tags: sqlite

I'm a fresher of rails and SQLite.

Here is my scenario:
I had `sqlite3` installed on my Windows Vista machine.
A blog application code had also been implemented at `c:\rails\blog`.
I brought up my command prompt and went directly to `c:\rails\blog\db`.
I ran the command `sqlite3` to enter the database console.
when I used the `.databases` command, no database was listed out? Why?
What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You probably didn't open the database itself

```
sqlite3 database.db
```

Remember, that in SQLite a database is just a file. As long as you don't open or [attach](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) one, there is no open one. On the other hand when you just open the database `.databases` feels a kind of useless, because you *know* which one you just opened.

Answer (score 23):

You must provide the database (path and) name to the sqlite3 command, e.g.,

```
Dev e$ sqlite3 my_test.db
SQLite version 3.7.7 2011-06-23 19:49:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /Users/e/Dev/my_test.db                                   
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run `sqlite3` with no parameters, a temporary database is created, which will be destroyed as soon as the program exits. This is what you did.

To access the database, you need to specify the name of the file that holds the database.

```
$ sqlite3 my.db
```