# how to get databases names in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to valid a SQL injection challenge on `root-me.org`. I want to retrieve the databases names with the command

```
1' SELECT * FROM my_db.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

But i get the following error: `SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, near "SELECT"`

Any idea ?

Comment: Is "1' " part of your statement?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

Possible duplicate of

[sqlite3 - how to list out database name using .databases command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705664/sqlite3-how-to-list-out-database-name-using-databases-command)